# Total War: Warhammer, get income as the choas faction

Tags: warhammer-total-war

So I decided to purchase the chaos expansion of Total War: Warhammer.  Regardless of my opinion on the content itself. I was wondering how to gain a X amount of income each turn. They are nomads so they don't have any towns, but are there way so that you can make certain you maintain a certain level of income for each turn?

Comment: There's been an overhaul of Chaos in a recent update, among other things it made it way easier to have a stable economy as Chaos by making buildings reduce upkeep a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one which is putting your armies in raiding mode. They have to be on owned land (not a region that was wiped out), depending on how wealthy the region is you get an income. There are achievements for various factions (Orc and Beastmen I think) for 2,000, 4,000 and 8,000 income from raiding.

Personally I find raiding income to be insufficient others may disagree. It is a limiting factor though as Raiding Mode has reduced movement and increased fatigue if a battle is initiated. You also need to leave wealthy (and thus more powerful) factions alive and their towns intact to be able to keep earning.

Playing as Chaos or Beastmen and (a horde faction) is my least favourite playing style in TW: Warhammer but I played and finished every factions campaign. My main financial strategy was to limit the amount of armies I had, building unkeep reducing buildings in the horde asap and maintaining a quick succession of looting towns, replenish troops, repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Each horde can actually build one [Palanquin of Trophies](http://totalwarwarhammer.gamepedia.com/Palanquin_of_trophies) -> [Pillar of Skulls](http://totalwarwarhammer.gamepedia.com/Pillar_of_skulls) that provides a small income of 200 to 300 a turn. It is enough to maintain the upkeep of that horde if you avoid recruiting too many high tier troops.

But if you looking for high income per turn to upgrade buildings and recruit more troops that will not be an option. The game requires hordes to raid/loot/sack to get money required for expanding.